# Automapper: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Coalesce used with type that cannot be null'

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper, .net-6.0

I am getting this error when trying to use the mapper profile in Unit test

Error:
`System.InvalidOperationException: 'Coalesce used with type that cannot be null'`

Stack Trace:

```cs
 at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateCoalesceArgTypes(Type left, Type right)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Coalesce(Expression left, Expression right, LambdaExpression conversion)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Coalesce(Expression left, Expression right)
   at AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.CheckReferencesCache(Expression valueBuilder)
   at AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.ConstructorMapping(ConstructorMap constructorMap)
   at AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreateNewDestinationFunc()
   at AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreateDestinationFunc()
   at AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreateMapperLambda()
   at AutoMapper.TypeMap.CreateMapperLambda(IGlobalConfiguration configuration)
   at AutoMapper.TypeMap.Seal(IGlobalConfiguration configuration)
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.<.ctor>g__Seal|20_0()
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration..ctor(MapperConfigurationExpression configurationExpression)
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration..ctor(Action`1 configure)
```

Image:
[image]

How to reproduce:

1. Create an NUnit project (nothing more)
2. Replace the code:

```csharp
using AutoMapper;

namespace UnitTestIssue
{
    public class TreeEntity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public InternalNodeEntity InternalNode { get; set; }

        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }

    public class InternalNodeEntity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<InternalNodeEntity> InternalNodes { get; set; }
        public List<LeafNodeEntity> LeafNodes { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }
   
    public class LeafNodeEntity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }

    public record struct TreeDto(Guid Id, string Name, InternalNodeDto Nodes, bool IsDeleted);
    public record struct InternalNodeDto(Guid Id, string Name, List<InternalNodeDto> InternalNodes, List<LeafNodeDto> LeafNodes, bool IsDeleted);
    public record struct LeafNodeDto(Guid Id, string Name, bool IsDeleted);
    public class Tests
    {
        private IMapper _mapper;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<LeafNodeDto, LeafNodeEntity>().ReverseMap();
                cfg.CreateMap<InternalNodeDto, InternalNodeEntity>().ReverseMap();
                cfg.CreateMap<TreeDto, TreeEntity>().ReverseMap();
            });
            config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            _mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            //doesn't matter, just to invoke [Setup]
            Assert.That(1, Is.EqualTo(1));
        }
    }
}
```

3. csproj package info:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <IsTestProject>true</IsTestProject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NodaTime" Version="3.1.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit.Analyzers" Version="3.6.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.2.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I tried using nullable sytanx with Guid, string, InternalNode, LeafNode but seems like I am not able to crack it.

Other thing I feel is that Coalesce is failing for conversion between List<Class> and List<Record>? But can't pin point on this.

This is a very simple project to teach some of the students about the basics of WebAPI pattern i.e.

Api Controller Action --> Service (map dto -> entity) --> repository --> context (save/retireve to/from DB)

Comment: Do you actually need `ReverseMap`, because the reverse map is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is recursive `record struct` mapped into reference type, [mre] will look like the following:

```
record struct T1(int i, List<T1> List) ;
record T2(int i, List<T2> List);

[Test]
public void Test22()
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<T1, T2>().ReverseMap();
    });
}
```

You can fix this by making both either `struct`'s or reference types.

So the quick fix will be making `InternalNodeDto` simple record:

```cs
public record InternalNodeDto(Guid Id, string Name, List<InternalNodeDto> InternalNodes,
    List<LeafNodeDto> LeafNodes, bool IsDeleted); 
[Test]
public void Test2()
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<LeafNodeDto, LeafNodeEntity>().ReverseMap();
        cfg.CreateMap<InternalNodeDto, InternalNodeEntity>().ReverseMap();
        cfg.CreateMap<TreeDto, TreeEntity>()
            .ForMember(entity => entity.InternalNode, expression => expression.MapFrom(dto => dto.Nodes))
            .ReverseMap();
    });
    config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```

[Created a github issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/4293).

Comment: The thing here is that, TEntity is class which can't be made struct. Because it goes into DbSet which expects TEntity to be a class.

Comment: And we chose DTOs as record struct as the simpler data structures for controller parameters

Comment: @BhanuChhabra what do you mean by "simpler data structures"?

Comment: Thank you @guru-stron
I ended up converting the record struct to record class.

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly the error is because your top-level DTO's need to be reference types, not value types.  Remove the `struct` keyword from your `record struct`

Comment: The issue seems to be only the "recursive" `record struct` mapped into "recursive" reference type.